# Ensuring the file only gets deployed when intact

Tags: python, fabric

I got this to make sure I don't get failed transfers messing stuff up:

```
from fabric.api import *

def do():
    put('filename', '/tmp/filename')
    output_target = run('md5sum /tmp/filename')
    output_source = local('md5sum ~/filename', capture=True)
    # am interested only in the 32 character checksum text
    if output_target[:33] == output_source[:33]:
        sudo('mv /tmp/filename /usr/local/bin/')
    else:
        abort('files do not match; aborting!')
```

For some reason, I think this is not necessary, that Fabric `put()` handles this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Fabric does not check for data integrity after transfer. You can examine the source code of [the `put()` function](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/operations.py#L254) and also [the `put()` method on the `SFTP` class](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/sftp.py#L198) if you want - you will see there are no post-save integrity checks there.

What's used underneath however is the SFTP protocol. It provides checking on the SSH level, so I wouldn't worry about file getting mangled during transport. But it does not do the exact thing you want, i.e. it does not check that the file was successfully saved to the hard drive and is identical to the original. You can learn more about that reading [answers to this question on Server Falut](https://serverfault.com/q/140573).

Comment: Is it okay to assume the transfer succeeded if a `put()` does not abort, removing the need for checking checksums?

Comment: I think so, but I can not promise you there are no edge cases. For example I don't know what happens when target machine's hard drive is full, and whether the behavior is even consistent between different operating systems and file systems. But when it comes to regular network errors you should be covered.